# Segmentation Fault 11 Building Binary Trees in C

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

When I run this Code to get the Length of a Binary tree I get a Segmentation Fault: 11 Error.
I've tried correcting it and the only way I can get it to run is by calling the size function just for the left or right nodes. When I run it this way (which according to me is correct) I get the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
struct node* right;
};

typedef struct node node;

node* newNode( int data ){
    node* node = malloc( sizeof(node) );
    assert(node);
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    return node;
}

node* insert( node* node, int data ) {
    if( node == NULL){
        return newNode(data);
    }
    else{
        if( data <= node->data ){
            node->left = insert(node->left, data);
        }
        else{
            node->right = insert(node->right,data);
        }
    }
    return node;
}

node* buildOneTwoThree() {
    node* root = newNode(2);
    root->left = newNode(1);
    root->right = newNode(5);
    return root;
}

int size( node* tree ) {
    int n = 0;
    if( tree == NULL ){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return size(tree->left) + 1 + size(tree->right);
    }
}


int main(){

    node* tree = NULL;
    tree = buildOneTwoThree();
    printf("size = %i \n", size(tree)+size(tree->right) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show what debugging you have done, what results you found and which line is raising the fault.

Comment: The program main stops in the printf() function, so I went to the size() function and commented little bits. The point where it stopped working is in the size( tree->right ) recursion.

Comment: [works for me on ideone](https://ideone.com/JPqsJc). Maybe you are running an older version of the code?

Comment: I tried it again, it does not run in my computer, could it be the architecture? I am using a Mac osx and compiling and running in terminal.

Comment: Do yourself and anyone else tasked with reading your code in the future a favor: *Don't use variable ids that are also **type** ids*. (ex: `node *node;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
node* node = malloc( sizeof(node) );//<<-sizeof(node) : It has been interpreted as a variable name, not the type.
```

to

```
node* node = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
```

Comment: I Love You, how do I give you a high score or something like that?

Comment: @user3689383 Please accept（click V） as long as it was solved.,